# Sequelize references nullable foreign key

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I'm trying to add a new column to my table. The problem is it required to be backward compatible so I want a new foreign key to be nullable. It seems to ignore the `allowNull` attribute.

```
await queryInterface.addColumn(TABLE, 'locale', {
  type: Sequelize.STRING(16),
  references: { model: 'locales', key: 'locale' },
  allowNull: true
});
```